# Line height (leading) possible in Interface Builder for labels

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

Is it possible to change the line height for labels in interface builder? I swear this was possible before but I can't find the option now.

FYI this is referring to the space between lines of text in a single paragraph (multi-line label)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible with the default control. The functionality you are thinking of might be the `Align baselines` option for UILabels. Note that you could implement this functionality pretty easily yourself using the NSString additions to CoreGraphics.